# Removing 'NaN' strings and [] cells from cell array in Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, cell, nan, empty-list

I have a cell array, given as

```
raw = {100 3.2 38 1;
       100 3.7 38 1;
       100 'NaN' 'NaN' 1;
       100 3.8 38 [];
       'NaN' 'NaN' 'NaN' 'NaN';
       'NaN' 'NaN' 'NaN' []; 
        100 3.8 38 1};
```

How can I remove the rows which have at least one 'NaN' string and empty cell []? Thus, in this case, I want to remove 3rd, 4th, 5th and 6th row from the above-mentioned cell array. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your cellarray the values NaN are defined as string and not as the "special" value `NaN`

In this case, you can use the functions `isempty` and `isfloat` to identify which elements of the cellarray are either empty or of type float:

```
% Remove rows with empty cells
idx=any(cell2mat(cellfun(@isempty,raw,'UniformOutput',false)),2)
raw(idx,:)=[]

% Remove rows with 'NaN'
idx=all(cell2mat(cellfun(@isfloat,raw,'UniformOutput',false)),2)
raw(~idx,:)=[]
```

In the first step you look for the empty cells using the function `isempty`, since the input is a cellarray you have to use `cellfun` to apply the functino to all the elements of the cell array.

`isempty` returns a cellarray of `0` and `1` where `1` identifies an empty cell, so, after having converted it into an array (with the functino `cell2mat`) you can identify the indices of the roww with an empty cell using the function `any`.

IN the second step, with a similar approach, you can identify the rows containing floating values with the function `isfloat.

The same approach can be used in case the `NaN` in your cellarray are defined as "values" and not as strings:

```
idx=any(cell2mat(cellfun(@isempty,raw,'UniformOutput',false)),2)
raw(idx,:)=[]
idx=any(cell2mat(cellfun(@isnan,raw,'UniformOutput',false)),2)
raw(idx,:)=[]
```

Comment: thank you so much for your response! Solution is very useful.

Comment: If one of the answers you'got solved your issue, you should consider accepting one of them to let the community know your problem has been fixed (I suggest the one from @YuvalHarpaz, which is more elegant, but, up to you).

Comment: Certainly, I will keep that in mind. Moreover, both solutions are very efficient in terms of computation time (with a larger data set). I have used the solution suggested by you. I do not have enough reputation score with my stack overflow account; thus, I can not upvote one of the answers.

Comment: @Sushil You do not need any reputation to accept an answer.  Please see [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Answer (score 1):

To find which row has 'NaN's run:

```
idxNan = any(cellfun(@(x) isequal(x,'NaN'),raw),2);
```

Similarly, to find which rows have empty cells run:

```
idxEmpty = any(cellfun(@(x) isempty(x),raw),2);
```

Then you can ommit rows you don't want using 'or'

```
raw(idxNan | idxEmpty,:) = [];
```

replace `|` with `&` if that what you meant

Comment: @ Yuval Harpaz, even this solution is very useful. Thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: thanks, me and the other fellow posted similar answers at the same time, so this is the same in essense